# android webview displaying blank page specific url only

Tags: android, webview

My webview only showing white screen son specific url. (It's working with for ex. google.com)

```
package com.cemcebi.beyanname;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://*****/");
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea that why it's not opening.

Comment: I'm not sure about this..!! But I can see that url is not well crafted for mobile version. And also I can see that it's a kind of government site. So it may not work I guess.

Comment: webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); set this

Comment: @CodeREDInnovations yes but ı can easily access it from ios devices.

Comment: @PraveenSP not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]I ran your code in my app and voila it worked.

First add the following line in your manifest file.

```
android:cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"
```

Now change the link from https to http and it works perfectly.

Let me know you why I did this..!!
When the original link is compiled I got a error like handshake failed SSL certificate returned -1. So I guess it mean the website has some issues. So try using this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Check the image it works for me your doing something wrong in your code check the ID and other.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, adding this fixed it:

```
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            String databasePath = webView.getContext().getDir("databases", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
            webSettings.setDatabasePath(databasePath);
```