# Android Maui Web View - blank page

Tags: android, ios, webview, maui

After implementing a `WebView` with one line of code everything is working fine:

```xml
<WebView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
         BackgroundColor="Red"
         x:Name="wbview"
         Source="www.google.de"/>
```

If I change the `Source` to `https://my.source.com:1234/` it's not getting displayed on Android, but on iOS, the website is displayed correctly.
What am I missing? Is it some design failures in my `styles.xaml`?

Change Url to my Url => working on ios not android

Comment: can you load that url in Chrome on the same device?

Comment: Did you try to change the https to http? Or you can try to add the `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the ``application`` tag of the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I posted an answer and hope it will help the people which meet the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
wbview.Source = $"https://my.source.com:1234/";
```

From the docs:
The Source property can be set to an UrlWebViewSource object or a HtmlWebViewSource object, which both derive from WebViewSource. A UrlWebViewSource is used for loading a web page specified with a URL, while a HtmlWebViewSource object is used for loading a local HTML file, or local HTML.

Also, note that the WebView height may have zero height. Add a container to auto grow the Webview to your screen.

```
<Grid>
   <WebView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     BackgroundColor="Red" x:Name="wbview" Source="www.google.de"/>

</Grid>
```

Source: [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?pivots=devices-android)

Comment: still blank and not working

Comment: Please send the code behind and page xaml

Comment: So i found out what the Problem was, i dont know why but i have to set UsesCleartextTraffic=true in the MainApplication.cs

Comment: This is a common behaviour if your ssl is not correct.

Comment: But why is it working on every other browser or OS ? I should be right configured

Comment: Well i had the same issue. It seems is related with android os. Just set UsesCleartextTraffic=true. In production environment you dont need to remove the setting, as your productions server will have a proper ssl installed.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

So cleartext traffic will be automatically blocked by the system when user access the domains which needs to communicate with over HTTPS.

For more information, you can refer to this case about [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted) and this one about [android webview displaying blank page specific url only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62135063/android-webview-displaying-blank-page-specific-url-only)